Ansible vmware dynamic inventory groups with multiple conditions
i've got a dynamic vmware inventory in Ansible:
---
plugin: vmware_vm_inventory
strict: False
hostname: vsphere.customer.local
username: '{{ vsphere_user }}'
password: '{{ vsphere_password }}'
validate_certs: False
with_tags: True
groups:
  linux: "('linux' in tag_category.Ansible)"
  windows: "('windows' in tag_category.Ansible)"
  all_vms: "('true' in VMs) and ('true' not in config.template) and ('vCLS' not in config.name)"
compose:
  ansible_host: >-
    guest.net
    | selectattr('ipAddress')
    | map(attribute='ipAddress')
    | flatten
    | select('match', '^10.0.10.*')
    | list
    | first
properties:
  - 'guest.net'
  - 'config'

Basically everything is working except for the new group i've created:
all_vms: "('true' in VMs) and ('true' not in config.template) and ('vCLS' not in config.name)"
What i want is a group that includes the hosts from
group:
  VMs: true

and excludes all templetes (config.template = false) and exludes all vCLS hosts (config.name != vCLS*)
I tried this aswell
all_vms: "all and ('true' not in config.template) and ('vCLS' not in config.name)"

I think it's possible, since i got a similar filter in an Azure dynamic inventory, but here the group is just empty (not showing up at all).
